# Checking if conditions to create an object are met inside vs outside the constructing function

Tags: design

Say I have a module that can to do two things: It can check if condition A is met and it can create an artefact B. The caveat here is that if condition A is not met, artifact B should not be created. If I am calling this module from the outside, should this check be performed by the caller or by module?

Version 1:

```
// Outside caller
if(conditionAIsMet()) {
    let myB = createB()
}

// Inside module
function createB() : BType{
    // Create B without any checks
}
```

Version 2:

```
// Outside caller
let maybeB = createBIfNeeded()
if(maybeB != null) let myB = maybeB;

// Inside module
function createBIfNeeded() : Btype | null {
   if(conditionAIsMet()) // Create B
   else return null
}
```

Note: I realize this might sound a bit abstract, I tried to keep it that way to be generally useful for future readers of this question. In my case the concrete example is we're sending a specific chunk of data to the user ("Artefact B"), so we want to only create it if the user hasn't received it yet ("Condition A"). Additional constraint is that checking the user has received it is a quite slow, so putting the check in both the outside caller and submodule code is preferably avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which area of your code best "knows" about, or is the "expert" about, `conditionA`.

1. If **conditionA** is strongly coupled to the **B** module (or class), then the check should probably be there (version 2). As well as the code for `conditionAisMet()`
2. If **conditionA** has little or nothing to do with **B**, the check should be outside (version 1).  This is probably the most common, and has less unnecessary coupling between A and B.

See [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)), "Information Expert"